# Angular shouldReuseRoute method breaks the url's

Tags: angular

I have a problem with `routeReuseStrategy` which defining `shouldReuseRoute = () => false` causes a url problem. If I define shouldReuseRoute as returning false, after navigating the url's are broken and these url's are refering different pages, not working well.

component.ts

```
constructor(public router: Router){

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
      return false;
    }
    //this code causing the problem
}
```

component.html

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a routerLink="home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a routerLink="about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a routerLink="contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add slash `/` to begining of each url

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a routerLink="/about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

this should fix the problem

Comment: It worked for me, but do you have any explanations on this ?

Comment: Unfortunately nope. I think the problem was Angular route strategy couldn't detect urls without slashes.